# what is the use of Maven in seleniumRC or WebDriver?

Tags: maven

Can anyone explain me, for what purpose we will use Maven with seleniumRC or WebDriver?   Is it like ANT - build.xml?

Your help will kindly appreciated!!

Thanks,
mra

Answer (score 0):

Maven's original purpose was to handle transitive dependency management, so a developer needed only specify their "top-level" dependencies (e.g., I need Spring version n.n and webdriver version x.y).

Those dependencies have their own dependencies. Resolving those manually for all but trivial projects is difficult and error-prone. Using Maven we can make things difficult and error-prone automatically.

Kidding aside, Maven provides a *lot* of functionality out-of-the-box that would make for a very large Ant `build.xml`. Maven *does* handle the build process, but it also downloads your dependencies, resolves transitive dependencies, runs your tests, generates reports and a project website, and a million other things through its plugins.

Check out the docs on the [Maven web site](http://maven.apache.org/), particularly the [Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) page to get started.